# Specify the start time of the command according to the website clock

Tags: javascript, html, button, time, click

I have this auto click button code,I want to set(add) start time for it according to web clock at specific time.
Thanks alot for edit and complete it.

here is my code:

```
let mainInterval =setInterval(() => {
    
 document.querySelector('.buy button').click();

    console.log('clicked');
}, 400);

 
let stop = 4000;     
setTimeout(() => { clearInterval(mainInterval); alert('stop'); }, stop);
```

website clock elements:

class="show-clock" clock="" now-time="nowTime">20:20:20

Comment: You just want to execute something at a specific time ? You could calculate the difference between now and this specific time, and put this offset into `setTimeout` ?

Comment: yes bro, I want execute this code at 8:00:00 clock time...I want to put time directly in code

Comment: `setTimeout(() => ..., new Date(your8DateTime) - new Date())`

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution:

```js
const scheduleTrigger = (futureDate) => {
    const timeMS = new Date(futureDate) - new Date();

    return new Promise((res, ref) => {
        if (timeMS > 0) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                res();
            }, timeMS);
        } else {
            rej();
        }
    })
}

//const futureDate = '2020-07-23T20:53:12';
// or
const futureDate = new Date();
futureDate.setSeconds(futureDate.getSeconds() + 5);

console.log('now');

scheduleTrigger(futureDate).then(_ => {
    console.log('future date reached');
    // start whatever you want
}).catch(_ => {
    // the date provided was in the past
});
```

Comment: thanks bro. I want my code start at  this time(8:00:00). can you complete with my code please?